# Plotly x axis values not same as input

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, plotly

I am trying to create a bar chart using the following table and code:

tracedata1:

```
Berth
01E                                 56.0
01W                                  0.0
02                                  59.0
08                                  92.0
09                                   5.0
14                                  19.0
15                                   8.0
16                                  68.0
17                                  30.0
```

bar chart code :

```
trace1 = Bar(x = tracedata1.reset_index()['Berth'], y = tracedata1)
data1 = [trace1]
layout1 = Layout(xaxis = dict(tickangle = -45))
fig1 = dict(data = data1, layout = layout1)
iplot(fig1)
```

and it gives me the following graph:

[image]

I dont get why the x axis is only showing the Int values and not any other. The x axis input is of object type.

EDIT:
df3 in question:

```
ATA                 ATD                Begin Receive    Berth Time       Days Spent
2018-04-14 03:50:00 2018-04-19 14:35:00 NaN                 29 5 days 10:45:00  5.0
2018-04-30 16:20:00 2018-05-01 12:58:00 2018-Apr-16 07:00   C2 0 days 20:38:00  0.0
```

Comment: you're passing the entire dataframe as your argument for `y`. What is the column of data you want to plot called?

Comment: `tracedata1 = df3.groupby('Berth').sum()['Days Spent']`
I Also tried this from the original dataframe :


`Bar(x= df3.groupby('Berth').sum().reset_index()['Berth'], y = df3.groupby('Berth').sum()['Days Spent'])`


The result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotly` is reading your x values, seeing some of them are numbers and automatically plotting the bars as numbers. We want to override that - so tell it your axis type is `'category'`. Here's some slightly neatened code:

```
tracedata1 = df3.groupby('Berth', as_index=False).agg({'Days Spent': 'sum'})

trace1 = Bar(x=tracedata1['Berth'], y=tracedata1['Days Spent'])
data1 = [trace1]
layout1 = Layout(xaxis=dict(tickangle=-45, type='category'))
fig1 = dict(data=data1, layout=layout1)
iplot(fig1)
```

Comment: Just tried it exactly how you wrote it, still giving me the same result.

Comment: Would creating a list From Berths and then adding a string to all values and then passing it through plotly help ? sorry if thats a stupid idea i just dont know what is going on here

Comment: Can you add in a sample of `df3` into your question? Try doing `print(df3.head())` and copying that in

Comment: I edited part of df3 in the original post, its only the columns i am using for this graph but the original has about 63 columns. Also i just tried with TIme instead of days spent and had the same issue

Comment: Thank you! that worked, and apparently adding a string to the Berth column also fixed it, but your solution is much simpler and looks Better. Thank you once again!